# How to run function when after endDrawer is closed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dynamic, widget, drawer, scaffold

I have product list page from which i opened endDrawer which contains cart item. if i remove cart items it does not update the product list page automatically. how to use **.then** function in endDrawer in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just Wrap your end drawer with a `DrawerController` and get callbacks when it is closed or opened, because Scaffold does make a drawer controller for it self and encapsulates it so you can not modify it.

The only other way I can think of is putting the drawer controller outside your main scaffold or showing it using `Overlay` if you are familiar with those.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
                child: UserAppBar(),
              ),
              body: PostsPage(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: DrawerController(
              child: Drawer(
                child: Column(),
              ),
              drawerCallback: (open){
                print(open);
              },
              alignment: DrawerAlignment.end,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like scaffold makes a `DrawerController` automatically and you can't have them inside each other.

Comment: you may also may want to look into state management. updating of widgets and lists should not be a problem in the first place. you can do it using streams and Blocs or any other way. I personally really like using ValueNotifiers and AnimatedBuilders.